# error al ejecutar el codigo

Tags: javascript, typescript

soy nueva en javascript me puede ayudar a decirme porque me saca este error

javascript y typescript... Estoy trabajando algo que se llama sharepoint framework

1.Estoy recuperando un json de esa url y luego tratando de pintar los datos en una lista para que se vean en la pagina, y me muestra el error que esta en al imagen:

lo que esta leyendo es un json

```
protected listUsers = async () => {
    //let url:string = 'https://fa-cosmosdb-qa.azurewebsites.net/api/RecomendacionBibliotecas?code=rjzLK9E5v2PxmTcDOeIqA8ss1TI-2PyQqnZ24uenRT8NAzFuyqO_1A==&documento='
    let url:string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const users = await response.json();

    let tableBody = ``;
    users.forEach((user:any, index:any) => {
        tableBody += `<tr>
        <td class='centered'>${user.id}</td>
        <td class='centered'>${user.name}</td>
        <td class='centered'>${user.username}</td>
        <td class='centered'>${user.email}</td>
        <td class='centered'>${user.website}</td>
        </tr>`;
    });
    document.getElementById("tableBody_Users").innerHTML = tableBody;
```

Comment: Quita la imagen y pega el código como texto. Las imágenes de código no permiten que podamos ayudar nada bien y no son bien vistas en este sitio. Pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para modificarla con ese cambio, gracias.

Comment: Parece que users no es un arreglo. Un `console.log(users)` puede ayudarte a ver qué es lo que viene en esa respuesta.

Comment: user es un json

Comment: prueba poner const users: any[] = await response.json();

Comment: con esta instrucción no me saca el error pero no me pinta los valores del json

Comment: Yo he probado la función y es correcta. Tu problema debe estar en otro lado